# Conflit with systems popup of IOS and rg.plugin.popup

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios

I am using xamarin.forms to do an app for ios and Android.
I am using Rg.popup as well.
The problem is: when I run the app in ios and before my rg.popup appear the system shows a system popup, my layout is strange...

[image]

How it can be

[image]

does Someone know how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote notification is not supported on Simulator, so system log an error about this and your code shows it with an alert. You need a real device to test remote notification.

To get rid of the alert view, find the code which shows the system alert in  `FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications` method in AppDelegate.cs. Forbid it when the error code is 3010(which is for the error).

Comment: But in my physical device, I get systems messages to...but always it ocurres I will get this error with my login popup